# Drawing contours for objects in C++ using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I wanna achieve to Measuring the size (like last attached image) for object  and also need to get calculate height & width of object in iOS application using OpenCV framework.

Successfully integrated CvVideoCamera and able to Start video

Now the problem came here in the ‘processImage’ method.

**What i have tried:**

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image;
{
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
    cv::GaussianBlur(gray, gray, cvSize(7, 7), 0);
    cv::Canny(gray, gray, 50, 100);
    cv::dilate(gray, gray, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cvSize(2, 2)));

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point > > contours;
    cv::findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::RotatedRect rect = cv::minAreaRect(contours[i]);
        cv::Point2f points[4];
        rect.points(points);

        std::vector<cv::Point> boundingContour;

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            boundingContour.push_back(points[j]);

        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> boxContours;
        boxContours.push_back(boundingContour);

        cv::drawContours(image, boxContours, 0, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**What need to achieve:**(Edited)

As GPPK mentioned link in comment [Measuring Objects](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) in C++.

Honestly i don’t know c++ but i tried what i can but struggling to move forward without knowing deeply. If anyone can help it will much Appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drawing contours is easy, drawing measurements is hard without extensive calibration etc. I think you're question is currently a bit too broad and needs refining. [this blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) details exactly what you want though so read through that.

Comment: @GPPK thanks for the link, that's exact things i wanna do.But i have to do in C++.Can you plz help on this.

Comment: well at this point you have complete pseudocode for your application, I would suggest attempting to get as far as you can by converting that code into C++ then post a new question with a more specific question